# In .NET Core EF, why Query run so much faster if .Select() is used than ToListAsync()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Why retrieving data from database is much much faster if Select() is used than ToListAsync()? I have 5000 dummy entries in a table.

my code:

```
private IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            int? skip = null, int? take = null, bool asNoTracking = false,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null)

            where TEntity : class, IEntity
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _context.Set<TEntity>();
                
            if (filter != null)
                query = query.Where(filter);

            if (include != null)
                query = include(query);

            if (orderBy != null)
                query = orderBy(query);

            if (skip.HasValue)
                query = query.Skip(skip.Value);

            if (take.HasValue)
                query = query.Take(take.Value);

            if (asNoTracking)
                query = query.AsNoTracking();

            return query;
        }
```

when the method is used like this:

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync<TEntity>(
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            int? skip = null, int? take = null, bool asNoTracking = false,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null)
            where TEntity : class, IEntity
        {
            return await GetQueryable<TEntity>(null, orderBy, skip, take, asNoTracking, include).ToListAsync();
        }
```

this takes 30 seconds!

But when this code is used:

```
public virtual async Task<IQueryable<dynamic>> GetDynamicAsync<TEntity>(
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            int? skip = null, int? take = null, bool asNoTracking = false,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> columns = null)
            where TEntity : class, IEntity
        {
            return GetQueryable<TEntity>(null, orderBy, skip, take, asNoTracking, include).Select(columns);
        }
```

this takes not even a second! 1 second max I think.

Why is that? Can someone explain? Even if I add all the of my table's column in the "columns" variable still it is so fast to retrieve. So what's the difference between the 2 queries? Also is it okay if await is not being used here? I cant' use await because it says that IQueryable has no GetAwaiter. It concerns me.

Thanks!

edit: added Service code

```
public async Task<ManyResult<LibrariesForTableDTO>> GetLibrariesForTable(DatatableSearchDTO dto)
        {
            var response = new ManyResult<LibrariesForTableDTO>();
            try
            {
                //var libraries = await _repo.GetDynamicAsync<Library>(columns: x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.Description });
                var libraries = await _repo.GetAllAsync<Library>();
                response.Entities = _mapper.Map<List<LibrariesForTableDTO>>(libraries);
                response.TotalFilteredEntities = libraries.Count();
                response.TotalEntities = libraries.Count();
                response.Success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "Error retrieviing the libraries.";
                _logger.LogError("Error calling GetLibrariesForTable: {0} - {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Comment: second returns just plain IQueryable ... obviously it doesn't query database at all

Comment: i don't get it. i'm retrieving the correct data tho? so is my way of retrieving the data wrong?

Comment: You're returning different things. Your first method (the one that is slow) returns the data. The second one (the fast one) returns a function that can fetch the data.
If you print the data to the console, you'll find that they both will take approximately the same time to run because then both will need to actually fetch the data.

Comment: `Select` is returning the shopping list - the steps of what to do. `ToList`(or any enumeration of the `Select`) is **doing the shopping**. Writing a shopping list is fast. Going to the shops and buying stuff is slow.

Comment: I edited my post guys, I added my service code that calls the query methods. The commented "libraries" return list of data. and the mapping of this still just take a second. the second(not commented) "libraries" takes 30 seconds. Can you guys tell me what part here is the "fetching the data"? Because I don't really get it when does it happen. I'm confused right now. Thanks!

Comment: The reason I have selected the duplicate that I did was due to its inclusion of the sentence `Nothing is sent to the server until we try to consume the result in the foreach loop.`. That is the fundamental difference between your code samples.  Your `Select` isn't actually executing the SQL - but the `ToList` is since it consumes (enumerates) the data.

Comment: ok2 now I kinda get it. But a follow up question, is it wrong to do it the "fast" way? because the difference is like half a minute and I think it does have a con(s) maybe? should I use the fast way? i'm using this in jquery datatable btw.

Comment: If it is actually slower (end to end) then it is likely that you are enumerating the `IQueryable` more than once. This is resulting in multiple database queries. In that case, `ToList`ing can be useful to avoid multiple DB hits.

Comment: i almost forgot, thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `Select` on the `IQueryable` does not execute the query, that's why it's fast.
When you run something like `ToList` or `FirstOrDefault`, it actually needs to enumerate the results, and that's when the query executes.
It essentially just adds a projection to the queryable object so that when the query executes, that projection can be translated to the SQL query etc.

So if you don't execute the query there, you are delaying the query execution for later, when the IQueryable is enumerated.

Comment: But I don't get it sir. If it does not execute the query, why i'm getting the data from database? IQueryable with Select does return my desired data. Why is that?

Comment: How are you looking at it? If you go through it with a loop for example, it will run the query at that time. Any tool that you use to look at the IQueryable data is going to enumerate it and thus cause the query to run.

Comment: I edited my post sir, I added my service code that calls the query methods. The commented "libraries" return list of data. and the mapping of this still just take a second. the second(not commented) "libraries" takes 30 seconds. Can you tell me what part here is the "enumerate" or the real "execution"? Because I don't really get it when does it happen. I'm confused right now. Thanks!

Comment: Linq - deferred execution. Here's an explanation https://medium.com/exam-70-487/deferred-execution-of-linq-query-39a925195b73

Comment: When you call Map on the mapper, that will run the query. Both calls to Count() will also run queries to get a count of results.

Comment: so it does "realized value is actually required" in the line of the mapping? or in javascript because i'm using the data in datatable? but that's not it right because it's in front end now hehe. so is it being used in the mapping? it's where the actual work does?

Comment: ok2 now I kinda get it. But a follow up question, is it wrong to do it the "fast" way? because the difference is like half a minute and I think it does have a con(s) maybe? should I use the fast way? i'm using this in jquery datatable btw.